# Override Windows copy (as in copy/paste) functionality?

Tags: c++, windows, copy, copy-paste

I'm working on a copy/paste program and I want to override the copy function so when ever you copy something the program copies it and not windows. Is this possible?

Comment: I think the proper way has something to do with your own clipboard, but this is really a "What if two programs did this?" kind of situation.

Comment: Well, that'd suck if two programs did that.

Comment: ***Pretty please, don't.***

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Because Windows doesn't copy things anyway. 'Programs do. And "overriding Ctrl-C" is also an indication you're on the wrong track. Ctrl-C terminates a console app, for instance.

Comment: The right path is to add different versions of the data from the most complex to the most simple, so any program can know about the data and know if it can use it.

Comment: @ManueldelCastillo: That's from the perspective of the data source and data receiver. See the first comment : "what if two programs did this" - there is no problem in having two possible data sources and two receivers. What **is** a problem is having two brokers/clipboards. I remember when X11/Solaris had that, really unfunny.

Answer (score 0):

No. The copy-paste is not done by Windows, so your assumption is wrong. You can see this from the fact that it's possible to copy many things that Windows is unaware of. For instance, parts of CAD drawings - Windows doesn't ship with support for that out of the box.

And obviously, *you* can't copy a CAD drawing component either. Remember, I'm not hiding information from you here. If things worked as you assumed, you would need to copy anything that an application wants copied, without any knowledge up front. In fact, you would need the capability today to copy objects that I will only write tomorrow!

In reality, copy-paste works by cooperation between the source and destination application.

Comment: Sorry, this is not exact. You can add data in different formats to the clipboard. Receiving program is responsible for checking these formats and use the best if able at all.

Comment: Of course it's not exact. Did you expect a single sentence to be? You're describing one aspect of the cooperation (format enumeration) in two sentences. That's still not complete, e.g. the copy-paste process needs to deal with process boundaries too. But all that is too much detail for this question, which is NOT about the basic functionality.